# MYSQL REPORTING

Tags: mysql

is there a more efficent way to get rows fro ma table from the current week, last week, current month and current year to this

```
    // current month
    SELECT * FROM crm_tasks WHERE YEAR( date_completed ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) AND MONTH( date_completed ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) 

    // current week
    SELECT * FROM crm_tasks WHERE YEAR( date_completed ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) AND WEEK( date_completed ) = WEEK( CURDATE( ) ) 

    // last week
    SELECT * FROM crm_tasks WHERE YEAR( date_completed ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) AND WEEK( date_completed ) = WEEK( CURDATE( ) ) - 1 


// current year
SELECT * FROM crm_tasks WHERE YEAR( date_completed ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a query similar to this

```
SELECT * FROM crm_tasks 
WHERE date_completed >= @FirstDayOfYear AND date_completed < @FirstDayOfNextYear
```

Where @FirstDayOfYear and @FirstDayOfNextYear are filled in appropriately.  If you have an index on date_created, this should work reasonably fast.  This can be altered for any period you want to use.